# Генерация массива в Битркис1с с точками для добавления на карту яндекс API

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс, yandex-maps-api

Добавил на сайт яндекс карту на которую добавляются объекты из файла вот в таком виде:

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "object/map2.php"
    }).done(function (data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
        map.setBounds(objectManager.getBounds());
        // отложенный рендер иконок после загрузки всего objectManager
        setTimeout(function () {
          renderIcons(data);
        }, 10);
    });
```

Если в файле "object/map2.php" вручную добавить массив с точками то всё отлично отображается на карте. Но цель такова что бы всё это происходило автоматически из админки Битрикс.

Было принято решение использовать для этого компонент "bitrix:rss.out", создал шаблон который полностью генерирует файл той же структуры что и нужна мне для вывода точек, но точки не хотят отображаться. Проверял вручную, открывал результат этого файла в браузере, копировал сгенерированный массив и вставлял в файл, и всё работает, то есть составлено всё правильно. Не знаю почему не работает первоначально, может быть  компонент нужно другой взять или этот передает какую то лишнюю информацию?

Как сделать так что бы файл генерировался и все работало?

Comment: Адрес файла указан относительный.

Comment: Да нет, адрес нормальный, в консоле видно что этот файл загрузился и статус 200 и можно просмотреть его

Comment: Открой сгенерированный файл не в браузере, а в текстовом редакторе. Проверь кодировку.

Comment: Скачал сгенерированный файл, засунул в папку и сказал скрипту открывать его и все работает. Тут как будто он его начинает открывать еще до того как он сгенерировался или при обращении скрипта он не генерируется, хотя в консоле, во вкладке сеть он показывает его как скаченый

Comment: Ну, тогда только отладкой. Ставишь прерывание в функции renderIcons, и смотришь по шагам, что происходит.

Comment: А структура какая? Json? Тогда, возможно, нужно поставить соответствующих заголовок в ответе, либо самому раскодировать приходящую строку.

Comment: Проблема решена. Вместо компонента bitrix:rss.out сделал страницу генерации ajax ответа и все заработало